# Create a perpendicular line of points to another line

Tags: qgis, point, line, perpendicular

i have two problems over here. QGIS

1- I need to create a perpendicular line to connect multiple points to multiple lines but these lines have to follow a sequence of column.

2- And these perpendicular lines can't be created of differents "id's".

In the image above, you can see the result (In red) that i want. The (Red Line) has to start on the point and connect to the "line.shp" (following column "MDE" from lowest to highest) creating a perpendicular line.

[image]

Comment: Have you been using the http://postgis.net/docs/ST_ClosestPoint.html function?